# MongoDB MongoException$Network

Tags: java, mongodb

We seem to be out of ideas on how to continue troubleshooting this issue. Suddenly we see the exception listed below being hit every few minutes.

This is a 4 Mongo Shard Setup. The 4 MongoS servers are proxied using 3 HAProxies. We aren't having any visible network issues between our application and shards. The mongo logs for the shards, config servers or mongos don't show anything out of the ordinary. The haproxies seem to be doing their job just fine. Any thoughts and leads on this would be most appreciated!

> {"@timestamp":"2016-02-10T05:10:23.780+00:00","@version":1,"message":"unable to  process event [ Request Id: [ eb8c702c-b3e7-4605-99a7-c3dcb5a076a9 ] - Event: id [ 49e0ae8d-f16e-448c-9b28-a4af59aa2eb0 ] messageType [ bulk ] operationType: [ create ] xpoint [ 10254910941235296908401 ] ]","logger_name":"com.xyz.event.RabbitMQMessageProcessor","thread_name":"SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1","level":"WARN","level_value":30000,"stack_trace":"java.io.EOFException: null\n\tat org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:50) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.5.jar:na]\n\tat org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:35)\n\tat org.bson.io.Bits.readFully(Bits.java:30)\n\tat com.mongodb.Response.(Response.java:42)\n\tat com.mongodb.DBPort$1.execute(DBPort.java:141)\n\tat com.mongodb.DBPort$1.execute(DBPort.java:135)\n\tat com.mongodb.DBPort.doOperation(DBPort.java:164)\n\tat com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:135)\n\tat c.m.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:289)\n\t... 56 common frames omitted\nWrapped by: c.m.MongoException$Network: Read operation to server prod_mongos.internal.xyz.com:27017 failed on database xyz\n\tat c.m.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:297) ~[mongo-java-driver-2.12.5.jar:na]\n\tat c.m.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:268)\n\tat c.m.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:84)\n\tat c.m.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:66)\n\tat c.m.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:869)\n\tat c.m.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:843)\n\tat c.m.DBCollection.findOne(DBCollection.java:789)\n\tat o.s.d.m.c.MongoTemplate$FindOneCallback.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:2013) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.6.3.RELEASE.jar:na]\n\tat o.s.d.m.c.MongoTemplate$FindOneCallback.doInCollection(MongoTemplate.java:1997)\n\tat o.s.d.m.c.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1772)\n\t... 47 common frames omitted\nWrapped by: o.s.d.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Read operation to server prod_mongos.internal.xyz.com:27017 failed on database xyz; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Read operation to server prod_mongos.internal.xyz.com:27017 failed on database xyz\n\tat o.s.d.m.c.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.6.3.RELEASE.jar:na]\n\tat o.s.d.m.c.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:1946)\n\tat o.s.d.m.c.MongoTemplate.executeFindOneInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1776)\n\tat o.s.d.m.c.MongoTemplate.doFindOne(MongoTemplate.j...","HOSTNAME":"prod-node-09","requestId":"eb8c702c-b3e7-4605-99a7-c3dcb5a076a9","WHAT":"ProcessBulkDiscoveredXYZEvent","host":"172.30.31.155:44243","type":"cloud_service","tags":["_grokparsefailure"]}

Comment: Which version of mongo?

Comment: Mongo Version is 2.6